# Hi. I have troubles with RETURN VALUE from THREAD function

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, return-value

My program must to search a file by name from some directory and search it through the threads!
Here I created TEMP folder for testing this search,included some different files and here searching for example ".cpp" file.But the problem is not here.
The compiler says "must return a value from ThreadSearch", and I've tried many return statements ,but all of it is not suitable,All that i found on internet cannot fix this error,and nobody has an error like in my code,I reckon this is a bug and in the void function it shoud be normal "return;" ,but it does not work and help, in other cases I got errors like "unresolved symbol",maybe somebody can help me with this!

here's my code!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
//#include<fileapi.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

#define thread_max 8
HANDLE FindFile;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
LPCWSTR file = L"D:\\VS-studio\\TEMP\\*.cpp";

void* ThreadSearch(void* args)
{
    int current_thread = 0;
    int num = current_thread++;

    for (int i = num * (8 / 4); i < ((num + 1) * (8 / 4)); i++)
    {
        FindFile = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData);
    }
    // return (void*)current_thread;
    // pthread_exit(nullptr);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    pthread_t thread[thread_max];

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_max; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &ThreadSearch, (NULL));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_max; i++)
    {
        (pthread_join(thread[i], NULL));
    }

    void pthread_exit(void* retval);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == FindFile)
    {
        cout << "error in finding file" << endl;
        cout << "Error" << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File found" << endl;
        wcout << "File name - " << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
        wcout << "File size - " << FindFileData.nFileSizeLow << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should use `std::thread` and say goodbye to `void*` and other ancient quirks

Comment: `int current_thread = 0;` is a function local variable. Each thread will call `ThreadSearch`, and each of those function calls will use its own copy of `int current_thread = 0;` so each thread will see it's `num` as `0`.

Comment: A function whose return type is not `void` must return *something*. Your function's return type is `void*` (not `void`) so it has to return something. If you don't care about the return value and just want to satisfy that requirement you can return `nullptr` in this case.

Comment: If you got to the point of getting "unresolved symbol" during one of your attempted fixes, then it probably fixed the problem and you would now be seeing a different, later error. It sounds like you are assuming all the errors are related to this immediate problem, but frequently in c++ when you get an error it will prevent other errors from showing up. So fixing one error can reveal more errors, but it doesn't mean the fix you just did is incorrect.

Comment: I got u François Andrieux